# Query crashing while using pg8000

Tags: sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, pg8000

I am making a query to Amazon Redshift table using pg8000 and SQLAlchemy. Sometimes my query is crashing with the following error.

```
pg8000.core.ProgrammingError: ('ERROR', '42P01', 'Relation with OID 1100223 does not exist.', '/home/ec2-user/padb/src/pg/src/backend/catalog/aclchk.c', '1423', 'pg_class_aclmask')
```

However, this is happening for only one table in the DB. And this behaviour is completely random. Not sure why SQLAlchemy is throwing `programmingError` and whether it is [correct](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/errors.html#dbapi-errors).

Comment: can you try the same without pg8000?

Comment: In Windows, I'm getting the following error without pg8000. Windows fatal exception: access violationWindows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374Thread 0x. This is only in windows and is happening randomly.

Comment: I suggest you start with a fresh ubuntu 18.04 install on ec2, then carefully construct your set up and repeat the steps, you can then report back on what happens on a stable environment. I suggest - without pg8000 if possible!

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249580/concurrency-issue-with-psycopg2-redshift-and-unittest. Something is caching query plans and you've removed a table that was used. Note that it is not SQLAlchemy that is throwing the error, but just forwarding it.

Comment: @JonScott I'm not facing any error in Ubuntu without pg8000. I moved to pg8000 due to the fatal exception happening in Windows. That issue is resolved by pg8000. However, it is creating the above issue for one particular table.

Comment: Hi @Niyas, this question probably needs some more information for it to get an answer. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see what other information you could provide.